# curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy in docker container

Tags: docker, curl, containers, docker-container

Inside docker container, when I run the
`curl google.com`
then I got a message:

> curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: proxy.local

vi ~/.curlrc In the container, there is a proxy setting.

```
proxy=http://proxy.local:3128
```

Have any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.